# Zend + TinyMCE use view variable in tinyMCE dialog; How do I access the view variable from outside of the Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, tinymce, zend-view

Zend + TinyMCE use view variable in tinyMCE dialog; how to retreive the view variable for a file outside the zend framework?

I' creating a plugin for tinyeMCE, in which the user can select a list of pages from the CMS.
I retreive the values from the database and pass these to the view file. This works on the page itself. Now I want to use this in the dialog screen of tinyMCE. The plugin uses a .php file with the dialogs content. I'm unable to use the `$this->variable` like I would normally use.

So the (bigger) question is: How do I access the view variable from outside of the Zend Framework? (or be part of the Zend Framework?)

**Additional info to answer**

Found out, that using the code below is possible to call an action from zf:

```
ed.addCommand('mcepagelink', function() {
            ed.windowManager.open({
                file : url + '../../../../../admin/tinymce/pagelink',
                width : 320 + parseInt(ed.getLang('pagelink.delta_width', 0)),
                height : 200 + parseInt(ed.getLang('pagelink.delta_height', 0)),
                inline : 1
            }, {
                plugin_url : url, // Plugin absolute URL
                some_custom_arg : 'custom arg' // Custom argument
            });
```

*Going back roots is off course depending on you application structure*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest pointing the URL for your plugin at a Zend Framework page instead. That way you can use the same (or similar) code, and use the view variables as normal.

Comment: I was working on a custom file and image browser, and using the callback function I found out that I'm able to point to a controller, so I'm using this approach for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a js-varaible to store the value of `$this->variable`?

Another approach is to initialize tinymce with an additional setting:

```
my_custom_var: '<?php echo $this->variable ?>',
```

which you can reffer to later in a plugin using

```
ed.getParam('my_custom_var');
```